# Sharing spatial code between SQL Server and Library projects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, spatial, sqlclr

We use SQL Server CLR in tandem with our webapp, largely for writing complex check constraints.

I need to write a class that works with spatial data, which will be shared between a CLR UDF in SQL Server and Entity Framework.

For Entity Framework, I use DbGeography. How would I represent a spatial type in a CLR UDF? How can I abstract it such that it works in both places?

Comment: Just some ideas - The built-in types `SqlGeography` and `SqlGeometry` are in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` You can reference these by adding Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll to your project (it's in the SDK/Assemblies folder in your SQL Server install dir). You can map between `DbGeography` and `SqlGeography` using the `Parse` and `ToString`/`AsText` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the MSDN page for [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), the type that you should use to accept `GEOGRAPHY` / `GEOMETRY` data as input parameters to SQLCLR objects and/or passing back as return values / result set columns is [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) / [SqlGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx), respectively.